# nginx upstream behaviour (if no hash header)

Tags: nginx

I wish to use:

```
upstream backend {
  hash $http_my_custom_header;

  server 1;
  server 2;
}
```

I wish to handle 2 cases:

- if I header has `my_custom_header` it should stick to single node associated with value of `my_custom_header`
- if there is no `my_custom_header` in request, std. round robin should be used

Is above config enough to achieve that? Can I assume that if there is no header used in `hash` loadbalancer will fallback to std. round robin?

I reviewed: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html but I did not found confirmation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of several request parameters to ditribute the load evenly while keeping the same clients stuck to specific upstream server:

```
upstream backend {
  hash '$remote_addr $http_my_custom_header $http_user_agent';

  server 1;
  server 2;
}
```

User-Agent and IP address of client will most likely be the same during the session.

Combination of these parameters will be constant during sequence of separate requests and will generate the same hash.
So different clients will be evenly ditributed accross all upstream servers no matter whether they have custom header or not.

**NOTE:** There is a possibility the queries of the same client will come from different IP addresses when broswer is configured to use some anonimizing service.